# Why does GHC typecheck before desugaring?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, ghc

Is there a good reason to run the typechecker first? It would seem that the typechecker would be vastly simpler if it ran on a smaller syntax, especially because with the current system every syntax extension needs to touch the typechecker. This question applies especially to arrow syntax, the typechecking of which [as described in comments here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/344#comment:26) is known to be bogus.

I imagine one reason for this would be not emitting errors that mention generated code, but this situation is already covered in cases where a `deriving` clause fails to typecheck; GHC knows that code was generated.

Comment: I think this is a very broad question, but seeing how all extensions to date are purely based on syntax and name availability (including ones like [`ApplicativeDo`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo)), there is no need for type-guided desugaring. The only real reason one would want to do this is to avoid the problem that desugared programs don't correspond to what the programmer provided, and when the compiler needs to provide diagnostic information (e.g. specific type errors), these programs need to be 'resugared' in order to refer meaningfully to the programmer's programs.

Comment: I think this was mentioned somewhere in [A History of Haskell](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dbg/readings/haskell-history.pdf) as a stylistic choice in GHC's implementation which has generally lead to a bit of overhead but improved likelihood to write nice error messages.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a section on this question in the [GHC article](http://www.aosabook.org/en/ghc.html) found in volume 2 of the book "The Architecture of Open Source Application":

> ### Type Checking the Source Language
>
> One interesting design decision is
>   whether type checking should be done before or after desugaring. The
>   trade-offs are these:
>
> - Type checking before desugaring means that the type checker must deal
>     directly with Haskell's very large syntax, so the type checker has
>     many cases to consider. If we desugared into (an untyped variant of)
>     Core first, one might hope that the type checker would become much
>     smaller.
> - On the other hand, type checking after desugaring would
>     impose a significant new obligation: that desugaring does not affect
>     which programs are type-correct. After all, desugaring implies a
>     deliberate loss of information. It is probably the case that in 95% of
>     the cases there is no problem, but any problem here would force some
>     compromise in the design of Core to preserve some extra information.
> - Most seriously of all, type checking a desugared program would make it
>     much harder to report errors that relate to the original program text,
>     and not to its (sometimes elaborate) desugared version.
>
> Most compilers type check after desugaring, but for GHC we made the opposite choice:
>   we type check the full original Haskell syntax, and then desugar the
>   result. It sounds as if adding a new syntactic construct might be
>   complicated, but (following the French school) we have structured the
>   type inference engine in a way that makes it easy. Type inference is
>   split into two parts:
>
> - Constraint generation: walk over the source syntax tree, generating a
>     collection of type constraints. This step deals with the full syntax
>     of Haskell, but it is very straightforward code, and it is easy to add
>     new cases.
> - Constraint solving: solve the gathered constraints. This is
>     where the subtlety of the type inference engine lies, but it is
>     independent of the source language syntax, and would be the same for a
>     much smaller or much larger language.
>
> On the whole, the
>   type-check-before-desugar design choice has turned out to be a big
>   win. Yes, it adds lines of code to the type checker, but they are
>   simple lines. It avoids giving two conflicting roles to the same data
>   type, and makes the type inference engine less complex, and easier to
>   modify. Moreover, GHC's type error messages are pretty good.

Comment: Readers: I would highly recommend reading the entire GHC article, it's very interesting.